# Handling error codes from multiple merchants

Tags: web-services, payment-gateway

I need to make custom error messages based on the error message that I get back from chase/merchant.

The problem is, there's so many merchants/banks that use different error codes.

What's a solution for this?  Is there anything more simple than making a database to handle all types of error codes?

Example

Wrong CVV entered

Costco Mastercard returns error code 522
Walmart Mastercard returns error code 702

```
SELECT ERRORMESSAGE
FROM ERROR_MESSAGE_TABLE
WHERE ERRORCODE = @ERRORCODE
```

Sorry I guess this is a very broad question looking for ideas instead of just straight answer technical help.  Not sure where to ask my question.

Comment: I don't see any other choice.  Have a lookup table with merchant_id, error_code as the key.  If code is not in table, have a catch-all error code for 'unknown'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the principles of SOA is that you never expose the internal of a provider to the consumer. Or in other words you don't tightly couple/bound your service provider and consumers with each other.

If for example Merchant A has an error message 100-wrong pin entered and you expose this error to your consumers/clients they are now tightly bound to merchant A.

If merchant A decides to change the error message (they upgrade their system which will happen) from 100 to BADPIN: Bad pin entered then all your consumers has to change. It is important that you abstract these details away from your clients/consumers. This will shield them from changes on you side.

So yes create a table with the merchant errors codes and your own errors code in and map these to each other. You consumers only have to worry about your codes then.

Hope this makes sense I can demonstrate with an example if you need it.

Comment: Looks like you're on to something here...  Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I just installed DB2 on my local machine, now it's working.  I'm having some difficulty getting it to connect to a remote DB2 server though.  I wish there was a manual somewhere.